# How to pan a texture programatically using gl_Position

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I am able to zoom a texture easily in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/7/) , but unable to pan properly.

Here's Code snippet for shaders :

```
var vertexShader = createVertexShader([
    'attribute vec3 attrVertexPos;',
    'attribute vec2 attrTextureCoord;',
    'varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;',
    'uniform float zoomFactor;',
    'uniform vec2 panCoord;',
    'void main(void) {',
        '\tgl_Position = vec4(attrVertexPos.xy  + panCoord.xy, 0, zoomFactor);',
        '\tvTextureCoord = attrTextureCoord;',
    '}'
  ].join('\n'));

//create and compile Fragment Shader
var fragmentShader = createFragmentShader([
'#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH',
    'precision highp float;',
'#else',
    'precision mediump float;',
'#endif',
    'varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;',
    'uniform sampler2D uImage;',
    'void main(void) {',
        '\tgl_FragColor = texture2D(uImage, vTextureCoord);',
    '}'
   ].join('\n'));
```

**Javascript code:**

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousedown = function(e) {
if(startX === undefined) {
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
} else {
    startX = lastX;
    startY = lastY;
}
isMouseDown = true;
};
document.getElementById('canvas').onmouseup = function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
    previousTranslation[0] = xVal/100*zoomFactor;
    previousTranslation[1] = yVal/100*zoomFactor;
};
document.getElementById('canvas').onmouseout = function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
};
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        xVal = (lastX-startX)/canvas.width*100;
    yVal = (startY-lastY)/canvas.height*100;
    console.log(xVal/100*2.0 + ',' +yVal/100*2.0);
    gl.uniform2fv(pan, new Float32Array([previousTranslation[0] + xVal/100*zoomFactor, previousTranslation[1] + yVal/100*zoomFactor]));
    }
};
```

I think there is something that could be done on the javascript side as shader looks fine . Any suggestions?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: just fixed it , was a minor error where instead of float ,I used vec4 for u_CosB and u_SinB , but as expected , the texture is not panning for me . Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say since you do not provide any information on what u_CosB etc. are. A new question with a MVCE would be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry ,I can't close it , I think the question was to implement panning functionality in webgl textures, it was not about fixing the error.

Comment: Then update this question and provide all the necessary information. What are the uniforms, to which values are they set?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: updated the fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/8/ , pan works fine but when you pan for second time , it behaves strangely , for example, try to move the image completely out of the canvas by dragging it twice, or thrice, anyway first time works fine .

Comment: When you want this to happen, you have to store the last pan on mouse up and always add the current pan to this.

Comment: I am already doing it, please check line no 234 in jsfiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/8/

Comment: You are not adding the current pan, you are override it with the current pan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you try to write a vec4 into a float, which is not going to work out. The multiplication of a float with a vec4 results in a vec4, thus you have something like this:

```
gl_Position.x = aVertexPosition.x * u_CosB - aVertexPosition.y * u_SinB
     float    =     float        *  vec4   -       float       * vec4
```

**Edit**

If this is really about panning (moving the object), then I don't exactly understand why there are sin and cos terms involved. In addition: Why is the x coordinate modified depending on the y coordinate? This would only be required if there is some rotation ongoing (which is not pan). In the end, the object is not visible at all, because you set the y-coordinate for all vertices to 0, which means they are collapsed to a line.

So to just implement panning, the code could look somehow like this:

```
//Contains offset in normalized device coordinates along x and y direction
uniform vec2 pan;

attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition.xy + pan.xy, 0, 1.0);
}
```

**Edit 2**

The way how you calculate the pan in `onmousemove` is wrong. You have to calculate the distance to the mouse down position (not sure what you are calculating now):

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousemove = function(e) {
if (isMouseDown) {
    var xVal = (lastX - e.clientX)/canvas.width;
    var yVal = (lastY - e.clientY)/canvas.height;
    gl.uniform2fv(pan, new Float32Array([xVal, yVal]));
    }
};
```

When you need it faster/slower multiply `xVal` and `yVal` with a constant factor. And it might be that you have to invert one of the directions when the pan goes in the wrong one.

**Edit 3**

The mousedown function now doesn't make much sense? Why should it behave differently after the first click? The only code there should be:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onmousedown = function(e) {
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
    isMouseDown = true;
};
```

Additionally, when calling the mouse-up function the second time, you override the value of `previousTranslation` instead of adding the current translation to it. Correct:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onmouseup = function() {
    isMouseDown = false;

    if (previousTranslation[0] == undefined)
    {
        previousTranslation[0] = 0.0;
        previousTranslation[1] = 0.0;
    }

    previousTranslation[0] += xVal/100*zoomFactor;
    previousTranslation[1] += yVal/100*zoomFactor;
};
```

Comment: upvoting it as , this was a part of the question

Comment: Okay what is pan.xy expected value?

Comment: The distance you want the object to be moved in the two directions (in normalized device coordinates, the same coordinate system used to specify vertices when no projection is used).

Comment: After a long time reading books and doing some examples, I am little bit comfortable with WebGL, I wrote this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/3/) , it zooms in/out on mousewheel , but pan is still a puzzle for me , can you modify the fiddle to fix the panning please?

Comment: That's not how SO works. Please post a new question containing the relevant code.

Comment: but we still have a unanswered question. I am sure other developers will mark it as a duplicate if I ask a new question.

Comment: Also, to be specific , I have changed my question, do I need to do anything else apart from this

Comment: I have another query where I want to pan only if my mouse is dragging the texture and not anywhere else in the canvas, can we do it as part of this question or shall I post a new question?

Comment: New question, because testing whether the mouse is over a triangle or not is a non-trivial problem itself.

Comment: great then , thanks a lot for your help , will post the new question shortly